# How can I represent a question in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How can I represent a question such as:

> Which colour turns into white when it is under the sun?

in first-order logic?
I think that if it was the following sentence:

> There is a colour that turns into white when it is under the sun.

I would represent it as:

> $(\exists x) IsColour(x) \wedge TurnsInto(x,White) \wedge UnderTheSun(x)$

Is there a different approach because of the question? 
Thank you

Εdit:
The original question is:

> Which liquid boils when its temperature is 100°C?

I wanted to have a similar example so that I could do my homework. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can't represent questions in predicate calculus.

Comment: @GitGud a similar question was given as homework. Should I answer that this is incorrect because it cannot be represented?

Comment: It would be better if you posted the exact problem. My guess is that it's being asked of you what color turns white under the sun, given some premises. This should be interpreted as asking to find a constant $c$ (a constant here is a color) such that  $IsColour(c) \wedge TurnsInto(c,White) \wedge UnderTheSun(c)$ is true. (I just copied the statement from your answer, I don't agree with how you modeled it, but this is not relevant for my point).

Comment: @GitGud We are asked to represent some English sentences in first-order logic and one of them is a question similar to the above. We do not have a specific dictionary we should use, just some sentences.

Comment: In any event, asserting the existence does not  seem to be the same as asking "which." We can often prove existence without answering the "which" question.

Comment: @Nancy Then yeah, the answer would be something like "not formalizable in predicate calculus".

Comment: As GG said, without the exact problem, we can't say for sure. It's not clear why you are not posting the exact problem. @Nancy

Comment: @GitGud thank you. If you want can you tell me why you do not agree with the way I modeled it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't really see the point in posting the exact sentence as the above one is quite similar to it. Which object A does B when it is under a situation C. (A,B,C are examples of the words).

Comment: If it is so similar, then why vary it? Perhaps you are unaware, but quite a few problems on this site are cleared up when people post the problem *exactly* as given to them. The only reason not to, as far as I can see, is to avoid being found out.

Comment: @Nancy Hopefully I answered your comment in my answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The original question is "Which liquid boils when its temperature is 100°C?". I wanted to have a similar example so that I could do my homework.

Comment: There is a branch of philosophical logic called "Erotetic Logic" (from ἐρώτημα - question). I think this phrase is enough to start a deep dive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try to answer the actual question, that you finally added in comments:

> Which liquid boils when its temperature is 100°C?"

First of all, "which" cannot be asked in first order logic. In general, first order logic cannot ask questions, although there is an implicit question for every sentence: "Is this true or false?" But you can definitely only ask "true/false" questions.

The best you can do is give an expression $S(x)$ in terms of a variable $x$ and then ask which $x$ satisfies it. The sentence:

$$\exists x(S(x))$$ simply asserts some value satisfies $S(x)$, which is hardly what we want.

I really think it is a broken question, and the best answer is that you can't state this in first order logic, but if you have a proposition $P(x,y)$ which means "$x$ is a liquid, $y$is a temperature, and $x$ boils at temperature $y$," then you can write:

$$P(x,100°C)$$

is the best you can do. And that is a very odd logic, because first order logic likes the universe to be of one "type."