# How to represent a question in FOL (First-order logic) or any other Formalism: exam question

Tags: first-order-logic, artificial-intelligence

as an exercise I am trying to answer questions from previous year's exams on Artificial Intelligence but I am stuck with the following one, for which I thought FOL would be a good candidate, and I answered 1. and 2. with it already, but I can't figure out how to answer point 3.

Any suggestions on how to do that in FOL (I already thought and [read that it is not really possible to represent questions in FOL](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108406/how-can-i-represent-a-question-in-first-order-logic#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20first%20order%20logic,%22true%2Ffalse%22%20questions.&text=simply%20asserts%20some%20value%20satisfies,is%20hardly%20what%20we%20want)) or with any other "Formalism or Knowledge-representation system"?

> Consider the following statements:
>
> 1. If the door is open and the window is open, then there is a draft in the room
> 2. If it is raining, then the window is closed and the windowsill is wet
> 3. If it is not raining, then the window is open
> 4. The door is open
> 5. The windowsill is not wet
>
> The candidate:
>
> 1. briefly describe a formalism or knowledge representation system that allows the previous statements to be expressed, highlighting its main features;
> 2. represent the knowledge expressed by the previous statements using the formalism or knowledge representation system described in 1. above;
> 3. **in the formalism or knowledge representation system described in 1. above, and given the knowledge expressed in 2. above, express the question "Is there an air current in the room?" and say what is the answer to this question in that formalism or system, explaining why.**

EDIT:

My answer to 1. and 2. would be something like:

We can use First Order Logic (FOL) as our representation system, as it has all the necessary elements to express the previous statements. We can use objects and constants such as *Door(d)*, *Window(w)* indicating respectively that object *d* is a door and that object *w* is a window, predicates and functions such as *open(d)* and *raining()* indicating respectively whether object *d* is open or not and whether it is currently raining or not. In addition to the possibility of using variables, logical connectives (negations, implications, etc.), quantifiers on variables, etc.

2.1 $\forall d, w \quad Door(d) \land open(d) \land Window(w) \land open(w) \rightarrow draftInTheRoom()$

2.2 $\forall w, ww \quad raining() \land Window(w) \land Windowsill(ww) \rightarrow \neg open(w) \land wet(ww)$

2.3 $\forall w \quad \neg raining() \land Window(w) \rightarrow open(w)$

2.4 $Door(d) \land open(d)$

2.5 $Windowsill(ww) \land \neg wet(ww)$

Note: the exam text and my answer to 1. has been automatically translated from Italian with DeepL.com (free version)

Comment: Welcome! You said that you solved 1. and 2. by yourself. Please show your work and also explain why you couldn't figure out the other points.

Comment: @DavidKrell Thanks for the suggestion, I made an edit with what I did so far for 1. and 2. For 3. I just don't think is possible to answer it with FOL (as it is also discussed in the other thread I posted) so I was looking for advice on what else could be used

Comment: IMO propositional logic is enough. 1) $OpenDoor \land OpenWindow \to Darft$ 2) $Raining \to \lnot OpenWindow \land WetWindow$ 3) $\lnot Raining \to OpenWindow$ and so on.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I guess you're right and we don't strictly need FOL but still how would one express the question "Is there an air current in the room?"

Comment: If "the windowsill is not wet", by 2 then "it is not raining". Thus, using it with 3 we have that "the window is open". Using it with 4 we have that "there is a [draft](https://www.wordreference.com/enit/draft) in the room". Thus, the conclusion is: "there is an air current in the room"

Comment: It's true that you can't represent questions as such in either first-order logic or propositional logic. But a Yes/No question is essentially the same thing as a statement; you are just *enquiring whether* it is true rather than *asserting that* it is true. Assuming that an air current is the same thing as a draft, then in the notation of @MauroALLEGRANZA 's first comment, this question (or its corresponding statement) is represented simply as $\mathit{Darft}$ (probably a typo for $\mathit{Draft}$, but you can call it whatever you want). And as Mauro's second comment hints, this can be proved.